# What is this template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

So I came across with this today about C++ template programming, can anyone explain to me what A(*)(B) as a template argument?

```
template <class X, class Y, class A, class B>
struct replace_type_impl<A(*)(B),X,Y,false>
{
  typedef typename replace_type<A,X,Y>::type (*type)(typename replace_type<B,X,Y>::type);
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type `A (*)(B)` is the type of a pointer to a function taking one argument of type `B` and returning a value of type `A`.

It's just another type. Your code is an instance of *partial specialization* of the class template `replace_type_impl`.

Answer (score 4):

It's a function pointer type, for a unary function that takes `B` and returns `A`.

This template replaces X with Y[*] wherever X appears in the function pointer type `A(*)(B)`. It replaces it separately in the return type A and the parameter type B, then combines them back together into a new typedef named `type`, which is also a function pointer.

[*] or possibly replaces Y with X, or perhaps does something completely different - I don't *know* what `replace_type` does, but I think it's a fair guess.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pointer to a function that returns an `A` and takes a `B` as its single argument.

Answer (score 1):

`A(*)(B)`

This is a type; pointer to a function that takes a `B` by-value and returns an `A` by value.